# Как указать правильно в условиях php css

Tags: php, html, css

Всем привет, вот кривой код php, подскажите как поправить это дело? Надо, чтобы в зависимости от нахождения на странице элемент либо был виден, либо нет. Вычитал на каком-то сайте, что

> (CSite::InDir('/index.php')

отвечает за условия нахождения на странице, а вот грамотно построить условия для работы не получается=\ heeelp!

```
<?php
if (CSite::InDir('/index.php'))
{echo '< li class="programs"><a href="/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/includes/img/Flag_of_Russia (1) 1.png" > style="opacity=1" </a></li>'};
else {<li class="programs"><a href="/"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/includes/img/Flag_of_Russia (1) 1.png" style="opacity=0" ></a></li>}
?>
```

Comment: что значит *в зависимости от нахождения на странице*?  если он не находится на странице - как он может быть виден?

Comment: Если я нахожусь на русской версии сайта, то подсвечивается 1 элеменет, если на английской то другой. 
Элементы находятся на обеих версиях сайта

Comment: Ну, тут не только в условии проблема. В else у Вас нет `echo` и кавычек чтобы вывести нужную часть, а до этого, `style="opacity=1"` в первом img не является атрибутом (этот `style` стоит после `>`).